# Searching for emails with specific string in subject with Node-IMAP

Tags: node.js, email, gmail, imap

My goal is to use IMAP to retrieve and display emails (pushed to an array called 'email') from a Gmail account as long as they have a specific string in the subject line. This is my first time using Node-IMAP. So far, I am able to return all emails found in the inbox, but as soon as I try to use `imap.search` it returns an empty array. I assume I'm missing something, but I can't figure out what.

```
var email = [];
imap.once('ready', function() {
openInbox(function(err, box) {
  if (err) throw err;
  imap.search([[ 'HEADER', 'SUBJECT', 'ABCDEFG'] ], function(err, results) {
    if (err) throw err;
  var f = imap.seq.fetch(results, {
    bodies: 'HEADER.FIELDS (FROM SUBJECT DATE)',
  });
  f.on('message', function(msg, seqno) {
    var prefix = '(#' + seqno + ') ';
    msg.on('body', function(stream, info) {
      var buffer = '';
      stream.on('data', function(chunk) {
        buffer += chunk.toString('utf8'); 
      });
      stream.once('end', function() {
        email.push(prefix + inspect(Imap.parseHeader(buffer)));
      });
    });
  });
```

Comment: Is the number of apostrophes in imap.search really as in the question?

Comment: @arnt Sorry, about that. No, that was just a typo in the question. The actual code had the right amount of apostrophes